# Posso dizer "remover" no sentido de "mover novamente"?

Tags: verbos, ambiguidades, prefixos

Estava conversando outro dia com um colega de trabalho, e caí na situação em que eu movia algo e depois movia novamente. Enquanto eu falava isso pensei em dizer que eu movia e removia, porém achei estranho tanto por nunca ter ouvido alguém utilizar essa palavra com esse sentido como pelo óbvio problema de ambiguidade.

De qualquer maneira, ficou a dúvida: posso dizer que removi algo, no sentido de que movo novamente?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Estou como tu: nunca encontrei o verbo *remover* que não no sentido de ‘retirar, levar’ (do lugar onde estava) ou ‘eliminar’ (nódoas, obstáculos). No entanto vários dicionários indicam ‘mover novamente’ entre os significados de *remover*. E aqui temos vários casos a considerar.

No caso do [Aulete](http://www.aulete.com.br/remover) e do Houaiss (Lisboa, 2003), a definição é simplesmente infeliz. Vejamos os exemplo com que eles ilustram o sentido ‘mover novamente’:

> Os trabalhadores removeram o televisor (Aulete)
>
> Resolveu remover o armário da copa (Aulete)
>
> O comparador de móveis usados removeu o guarda-roupa (Houaiss, Lisboa 2003)

Ora creio que qualquer falante nativo entenderia o verbo *remover* destes exemplos como ‘retirar, levar’ (do lugar onde estava), e não como ‘mover novamente’. Claramente este uso de *remover* não é o que tu pretendes.

A [Infopédia](https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/remover), [Priberam](https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/remover) e [Aurélio](https://dicionariodoaurelio.com/remover) (Priberam e Aurélio online são a mesma coisa) também trazem ‘tornar a mover’ ou ‘mover novamente’, mas sem exemplos não nos servem de grande coisa.

O Michaelis e o dicionário da Academia das Ciências de Lisboa (2008) é que já trazem a definição e exemplos mais ou menos como tu queres:

> **1** Tornar a mover: *Ia-se desentorpecendo e removia o tronco e os membros* [(Michaelis).](http://michaelis.uol.com.br/busca?id=13WYY)
>
> **1.** Fazer mover ou mover-se outra vez. *O velho removia o moinho. A mãe removia-se no sofá.* (Academia das Ciências de Lisboa.)

Agora, foi a primeira vez que encontrei este tipo de uso. Mas não é nada do outro mundo eu estar a ler um livro e deparar-me com um uso que nunca tinha encontrado antes. Então fui procurar no [Corpus do Português](http://www.corpusdoportugues.org/hist-gen/), a ver se encontrava usos deste tipo. Entre as quase quatrocentas ocorrências do verbo *remover* no Corpus, encontrei uma deste tipo, de 1859 (ênfase minha):

> Porque cantas, oh Vate? porque cantas?
>   Qual é a tua missão? O que és tu mesmo?
>   Para ti nada é morto, nada é mudo;
>   Co’o sol, e o céo, e a terra, e a noite fallas.
>   Tudo te escuta; e para responder-te,
>   Do passado o cadaver **se remove**,
>   E do tumulo seu a fronte eleva;
>   […]
>   [(Domingos José Gonçalves de Magalhães, “O Vate”, *Suspiros Poeticos e Saudades*, 1859.)](https://books.google.pt/books?id=uoRfAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA29&dq=%22Do%20passado%20o%20cad%C3%A1ver%20se%20remove%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiT_uOjptTSAhXG64MKHU15ArMQ6AEIfDAO#v=onepage&q=%22Do%20passado%20o%20cad%C3%A1ver%20se%20remove%22&f=false)

E, e, e… fico na dúvida se o poeta não queria antes dizer que o cadáver se retira do passado.

Agora, lá por *remover* não ser usado neste sentido, nada te impede que o faças. Nem sequer precisas da autorização do dicionário. É preciso é que os interlocutores te entendam. A possibilidade de ambiguidade não é exclusiva do verbo *remover*, e não é insuperável. É uma questão de escolheres acertadamente as palavras. Os exemplos do Michaelis e do dicionário da Academia são claros. Os seguintes também:

> Ficámos com os cabelos em pé quando ouvimos o cadáver remover-se no caixão.
>
> Deram-me um quadro. Removi-o pelas paredes todas da casa e não atinei com um sítio onde o colocar.
>
> Fico furibundo quando acordo a altas horas com o barulho da vizinha de cima a mover e remover mobília.

É natural que estas frases causassem uma certa perplexidade inicial ao ouvinte, mas seriam entendidas. Em situações formais, eu não usaria *remover* com este sentido; usariam uma linguagem mais conservadora. Mas isto é como em tudo: escolhe-se a linguagem mais apropriada às cincunstâncias.

Comment: O que queres dizer com "Priberam e Aurélio online são a mesma coisa"? Os dois dicionários têm a mesma origem e fonte de dados?

Comment: @ANeves Creio bem que sim. Todos os verbetes que eu comparei são iguais nos dois. O Earthling foi quem notou isso já há muito tempo; e o Aurélio online não é igual ao Aurélio em papel.

Answer (score 4):

Poder, até pode, é um significado previsto pelo [Aulete](http://www.aulete.com.br/remover), pelo [Aurélio](https://dicionariodoaurelio.com/remover) e pelo [Priberam](https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/remover), então dá para considerá-lo *dicionarizado*. Mas os interlocutores sentirão dificuldades de compreender o que está sendo dito, por causa da ambiguidade que você mesmo citou.

O uso da palavra também depende do significado que as demais pessoas atribuem a ela. Imagine se você dissesse que estava no trabalho a *produzir e reproduzir*? Certamente, levá-las-ia a pensarem algo distinto do que você quis dizer.

Comment: Exemplo interessante - em minha profissão é comum utilizarmos o termo reproduzir quando queremos reexecutar os passos que teve como consequência um problema de software - e raramente associam com outra forma de reprodução, mas de fato a ambiguidade está presente. De qualquer forma, parece que remover realmente não é comum pelo conflito entre os verbos, obrigado ambos se referem a algo. Obrigado pela contribuição: remover é reconhecido como válido.

Comment: Ramon o que me surpreendeu mais foi que «remover» não aparece com o significado de apagar no dicionário.

Comment: Acho que *remover*  com o significado de "apagar" é considerado um anglicismo (de *to remove*) e é por isso que não está no dicionário. Porém *remover* como "afastar" é no Priberam e não é difícil fazer a relação.

Comment: @JorgeB. Vem no Aulete e no Michaelis.